# Can we perform stratify for linear regression model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model, linear-regression, train-test-split

I wanted to perform stratify method while splitting tran_test_split for linear regression problem.

I know that stratify will perform on classification problems as it excepts 2 or more classes

what to know is there any method or way to perform this method for linear regression

is there a standard way to do this? if so, is there an implementation in sklearn?

Comment: What do you expect `stratify` to do in case of a regression problem?

Comment: Please ask questions about writing and fixing **code**, not general questions about machine learning strategies and theory. That's what [`Cross Validated`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and the Data Science Stack Exchange are for.